# Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager

Tags: mysql, glassfish, jackrabbit

I have deployed Jackrabbit 2.6.4 in Glassfish 4 using jackrabbit-jca-2.6.4.rar.

Everything works when I use the following configuration (Derby via JDBC):

```
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager">
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
```

but when I switch to this (Mysql via a datasource):

```
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager">
      <param name="url" value="jdbc/MySQLDataSource"/>
      <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
```

> No Runtime properties
>   Database Vendor : null
>   Create Tables at Deploy : false
>   Delete Tables at Undeploy : false into class com.pepedigital.omakase.template.boundary.TemplateManager: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jcr/repository' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
>       at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
>       ... 70 more
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jcr/repository' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jcr/repository} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to create repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager]]
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
>       ... 73 more
>   Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Communication exception for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/jcr/repository} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to create repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager]
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:513)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.util.JndiNamingObjectFactory.create(JndiNamingObjectFactory.java:90)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
>       ... 77 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to create repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager
>       at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:200)
>       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
>       ... 85 more
>   Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: Failed to create repository: Cannot instantiate persistence manager org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.MySqlPersistenceManager
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory.createRepository(JCAManagedConnectionFactory.java:220)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.jca.JCAManagedConnectionFactory.createConnectionFactory(JCAManagedConnectionFactory.java:153)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:156)
>       ... 88 more
>   ]]

I have configured a Mysql JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Connection Resource (jdbc/MySQLDataSource) in Glassfish and placed mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar in the domain/lib directory. I can successfully ping the database via the Glassfish JDBC Connection Pool page in the Admin UI.

Am I missing something in the JackRabbit PersistanceManager configuration?

**UPDATE 1**

If I don't use my datasource and instead use a JDBC URL in my PersistanceManager configuration to connect to the database it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Mysql JDBC connection pool was not configured correctly.

In order to get it to work I had to set the following properties:

- User
- Password
- DatabaseName
- ServerName
- Url
- URL

I also had to repeat the database and server name in the Url and URL fields e.g.

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name

At this point I'm not sure why there is a Url and a URL property but setting both of them to the above URL worked.